# Trying to get UILocalNotification to display immediately

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

In my app I’m simply trying to trigger a local notification to pop up immediately. It works in the simulator and on my iOS device, but I’ve been getting emails from users saying it doesn’t work for them (and the app doesn't appear in the notification center). Am I missing anything from my implementation of local notifications?

Code to display alert:

```
 UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
 localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
 localNotification.alertBody = @"Message goes here";
 localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]; //Could be the problem?
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

App Delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    ...    
    // Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (locationNotification) {
        // Set icon badge number to zero
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }

    ...
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Maybe its a timeZone issue and I should switch to presentLocalNotificationNow? Rather than scheduleLocalNotification?

I don't understand why my users are experiencing this problem while it works on my device.

EDIT***
I've been having this problem with users of iOS7, **not iOS8** (where I understand I have to register the app somewhere in an app delegate method)

Answer (score 0):

Notifications and badging require new permissions in iOS 8.  That could be the source of the problem.

If the users denied permissions for notifications and forgot, that could cause the problem.

Comment: Probably should have mentioned this above, but all current users experiencing this problem are on iOS7, not iOS8

Answer (score 0):

For iOS8 you must register for notiications (request user permissions)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Just made a quick edit before you posted this. The users that are experiencing this problem are on iOS7, not iOS8. I would love to add the code you posted to my project (as the users experiencing this problem say the app doesn't appear in the notification center), but I don't think it would solve the problem at hand